# How do you calculate the average of 2 line gradients efficiently?

Tags: geometry

I have 2 lines:

```
y = m1 * x
y = m2 * x
```

How would I efficiently calculate the average of the 2 gradients m1 & m2?

The obvious method would be something like:

```
tan((atan(m1)+atan(m2))/2)
```

But this is rather slow to compute, is there a faster method?

Comment: I think you want the bisector of the angle formed by the two lines, rather than the average slope. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a point on each line, with unit distance from the origin:
$$
P_1=\left({1\over\sqrt{1+m_1^2}}, {m_1\over\sqrt{1+m_1^2}}\right),
\quad
P_2=\left({1\over\sqrt{1+m_2^2}}, {m_2\over\sqrt{1+m_2^2}}\right).
$$
The bisector of $\angle P_1OP_2$ passes then through the midpoint $M$
of $P_1P_2$:
$$
M={1\over2}\left({1\over\sqrt{1+m_1^2}}+{1\over\sqrt{1+m_2^2}}, {m_1\over\sqrt{1+m_1^2}}+{m_2\over\sqrt{1+m_2^2}}\right)
$$
and the slope of $OM$ is
$$
m={y_M\over x_M}={m_2\sqrt{1+m_1^2}+m_1\sqrt{1+m_2^2}\over\sqrt{1+m_1^2}+\sqrt{1+m_2^2}}.
$$
Of course, two intersecting lines have two angle bisectors, perpendicular between them. Hence the slope of the other bisector is $-1/m$.

Comment: You are correct yes, it is the angle bisector I am looking for, thank you for the terminology. This is exactly what I was looking for :) (not really sure why someone closed the question...)

Comment: Here is a slightly faster form (thanks for wolfram alpha) which only requires 1 sqrt: (sqrt((m1^2 + 1) * (m2^2 + 1)) + m1*m2 - 1) / (m1 + m2)